# x is prefixed to the values of environment variables. The values (prefixed with x) of environmental variables are then compared

Tags: csh

I am reviewing a code written by another person.
I am seeing lines that look  like these:

```
   setenv VAR1     val1
   setenv VAR2     val2
   if (xval1 == xval2 ) exit 0
```

What does the line 3 of the above code do?
The part that I am do not understand is happens when the x is prefixed with val1 and val2.

Comment: it is poorly written `csh` code. I think they mean `if ( x"$val1" == x"$val2" )`  . Using `x"$val1"` is a way to avoid a run-time error. Think of what would happen if you had `if ( "$val1" == "$val2" )` and one or both variables were empty. You would get an error msg, something like "binary test missing an argument.". To further help understand your issue, run that small file with `#!/bin/csh -vx` as the first line. You will see each line before it is executed, and also see a separate version with all the variables converted to their values. A great debugging tip for all shells. Good luck!

Comment: Arg, no, the original authors **may mean** to use `if ( x"$VAR1" == x"VAR2" )`. For some reason they have placed the value of the variable into the `if` test. Really bad csh code ;-) Another more likely test would be `if ( x"$VAR1" == "xval1")` etc. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Can you explain what makes the code bad? Did you mean the could have written to test the existence of these variables first and compare the variables  only if both variables exist?

Comment: the examples I have given you are the "correct" way to implement such tests. The examples you inlcude do even use the `$` which is a key elemnent in the shell to designate that what follows is a variable. Again `xval1` should be at least `x$val` and good coding practice would allow for spaces in the `$val` value, so "correct" is to use `x"$val"`. I don't have a `csh` handy to test with, but I'm almost certain that the lack of spaces surronding the `(` and `)` chars are also errors.  Good luck.

Comment: If you're going to be maintaining a bunch of `csh` code without the authority to rewrite it in `bash`, the look for then 'The C Shell Programming Guide' (or similar) by Andersen. Good luck.